# Slim Framework Pagination

Tags: php, pdo, pagination, slim

Hello so I am using slim framework together with PDO connection and is having a big(for me) problem. I wanted to switch with eloquent orm instead of normal try and catching PDO but 45% is already done in my project. So this is my sample code so far

```
$app->get('/data', function () use ($app) {
    try {
        $data = $stmt->query("SELECT * FROM tableName");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die('Error.');
    }
    $app->render('data.html', array(
            'data' => $data
        ));
});
```

How can I put pagination with slim framework? Is there a solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide some Parameter to your route - I'm not sure about the current syntax in Slim2, so i will explain this with GET params.

`/data`

No paginate param is set so this would be the first page - provide default params.

`/data?page=2&limit=10`

Page 2 - Limit is optional (but the default for this is required). With that params you can "calculate" where your dataset is.

```php
//not tested

$app->get('/data', function () use ($app) {
    //pls validate that are numbers
    $page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;

    $offset = (--$page) * $limit; //calculate what data you want
    //page 1 -> 0 * 10 -> get data from row 0 (first entry) to row 9
    //page 2 -> 1 * 10 -> get data from row 10 to row 19

    $countQuery = $stmt->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
    $dataQuery = $stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
    $dataQuery->bindValue(':limit', $limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $dataQuery->bindValue(':offset', $offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT); 

    try {
        $count = $countQuery->execute();
        $data = $dataQuery->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die('Error.');
    }
    $app->render('data.html', array(
        'data' => $data,
        'count' => $count
    ));
});
```

For better handling you could write a simple Pagination helper class.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I put pagination with slim framework?

You can probably use Zend Paginator http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html . See @mwop own Paginator class and how he does this  https://github.com/weierophinney/mwop.net/blob/266eea772717f681936d06425e85bc008a22b6e8/src/Blog/PdoPaginator.php

There is another one https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta . You can try one of them.

Regarding your question about moving to Eloquent, it is upto you.

Thank you